# How does Instagram app show images? What is principle

Tags: android, instagram, android-bitmap

I'm curious how Instagram app show images.
If you look at Instagram app, it shows multiple images at the (almost) same time.
If you scrolled down, progress bar showing up and other group of images are shown.
I roughly guess that they use multithread for downloading and showing images. But I don't know the details.
What is the principle of showing multiple images at the same time?

Comment: I would look up "HTTP async" to find material on this.

Comment: You don't mean [Lazy Loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load images in a ListView or a RecyclerView using different image downloading and caching libraries like picasso/glide and add an OnScrollListener to your list which fetches more data when user scrolls through his feed. Do look at how to implement [infinite scrolling](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) in your app

Answer (score -1):

Images are stored on a database and shown as a listview I believe. There is a youtube tutorial out there where a guy made an entire instagram clone